# Pyspark Exceptions : [JAVA_GATEWAY_EXITED] Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

Tags: python, java, docker, apache-spark, pyspark

Yes, I know I'm going to be told it's a duplicate, but it's not.

When I try to connect to my Apache Spark via my Bitnami/Spark container, I always get this error.

```
Error : unable to find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit
Caused by : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Users\azeve\Desktop\École\MT4\DEVOPS\RENDU_DEVOPS_MT4\src\main.py", line 40, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master(f'spark://spark-master:7077').appName("SimpleApp").getOrCreate()
  File "D:\Users\azeve\Desktop\École\MT4\DEVOPS\RENDU_DEVOPS_MT4\.venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 497, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "D:\Users\azeve\Desktop\École\MT4\DEVOPS\RENDU_DEVOPS_MT4\.venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 515, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "D:\Users\azeve\Desktop\École\MT4\DEVOPS\RENDU_DEVOPS_MT4\.venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 201, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "D:\Users\azeve\Desktop\École\MT4\DEVOPS\RENDU_DEVOPS_MT4\.venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 436, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "D:\Users\azeve\Desktop\École\MT4\DEVOPS\RENDU_DEVOPS_MT4\.venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 107, in launch_gateway
    raise PySparkRuntimeError(
pyspark.errors.exceptions.base.PySparkRuntimeError: [JAVA_GATEWAY_EXITED] Java gateway process exited before sending its port number.
```

As I've seen in several places on the internet,

- At first, i tried with jdk8 but it didn't work
- I uninstalled JAVA then installed jdk 11,
- I also added JAVA_HOME to my path and when I type java -version, I get :
  `openjdk version "11.0.22" 2024-01-16 OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.22+7 (build 11.0.22+7) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.22+7 (build 11.0.22+7, mixed mode)`
  as answer.
- I was careful to align my PySpark version with that of my Bitnami Spark Cluster in 3.5.0.
- My python version is Python 3.12.1
- The ports on my spark master are 8080 for the webUI and 7077 for the Spark.

Here's the code I'm trying to run

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf

from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    conf = SparkConf()
    conf.setAll(
        [
            (
                "spark.master",
                "spark://spark-master:7077"
            ),
            ("spark.driver.host", "local[*]"),
            ("spark.submit.deployMode", "client"),
            ("spark.driver.bindAddress", "0.0.0.0"),
            ("spark.app.name", "HelloWorld"),
        ] 
    )
    
    spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()


    df = spark.createDataFrame([("Hello World",)], ["greeting"])
    df.show()

    spark. Stop()
```

In the pySpark config I tried for "spark.master" :

- spark://127.0.1.1:7077
- spark://localhost:7077
- spark://spark-master:7077
- spark://host.docker.internal:7077

And have also tried for "spark.driver.host" :

- The IP of my machine on my internal network
- Container IP
- 127.0.0.1
- localhost

I really hope you can help me, I used this video to set everything up: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luiJttJVeBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget it, I've finally found my trouble,
was a PATH problem because of venv.
When I did $JAVA_HOME in my python environment, I had the variable return, but I don't know why the script couldn't use it.
Everything worked itself out when I launched directly from my terminal without venv.